# The area of the strip

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, surfaces, curves

Let $\gamma$ be a convex smooth plane curve of length $l$.
I need to compute the area of the strip swept by the outer normal segments of length $r$ to $\gamma$ and the length of the outer boundary oval of the strip.
I assume that a parameterization of the curve is given. But in any case, I have no idea how to decide. I tried to do this for the circle, but it didn't work either.

Comment: For arcs of the same length on circles of different sizes, the area is different, so more information is needed than the values of $\ell$ and $r. \qquad$

Comment: @Michael Hardy It's a bounded curve. So values of $ℓ$ and $r$ are enough.

Comment: If the curve is closed, the area of the strip is $\ell r + \pi r^2$, see answers of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/723200) and [that](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/58467).

Comment: @WIT : I'm guessing you meant it is a closed curve. But your question doesn't say that.

Comment: @Michael Hardy: yes. I got it wrong. I meant closed  curve.

Comment: @achille hui: thank you!

Comment: If a parameterization of $\gamma(t)$ is given, then you can find a parameterization of the outer curve as $\eta(t)=\gamma(t)+r N(t)$, where $N(t)$ is the unit normal to $\gamma(t)$ and find the enclosed area by say Green's theorem.